# JavaScript login function not working using WebSQL

Tags: javascript, cordova, web-sql

I am attempting to do a login function using WebSQL and JavaScript. I have written a function the takes one argument(`email`). The function is supposed to search the database for an existing email then it should return an alert stating whether the email exists or not.

I further wan to use that function to search if a a correlating password exits for the email, if it does, it should log the user in, if not it should return a message. All help would greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
function email_exists(email) {
  mydb.transaction(function(transaction) {
    transaction.executeSql("select id from user where email= " + email + " ", [], function(tx, result) {
        alert("email exists");
      },
      function(error) {
        alert("Email does not exist");
      });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this,

```
function email_exists(email) {
    db.transaction(function (tx) { 
        tx.executeSql(
            'SELECT * FROM user WHERE email=? LIMIT 1',
            [email], 
            function (tx, result) { 
                if(result.rows.length){
                    // user found
                    alert("User found - ", result.rows[0]);
                }
                else {
                    // email does not exists
                    alert("User not found");
                }
            },
            null
        ); 
    });
}
```

One Important thing to note here is that You can avoid sql injection using the substitution approach (`?`) rather than concatenating query params in SQL query.

Read further from [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/)

Comment: thank you very much mohit, i will attempt it this way and send back feedback.

Comment: @ThandokLuthuli, i am glad that it helped. You can close the question now. In case, you have some more unresolved issues, pls mention.

Comment: i want to further use this function to check for a matching password for the email then log the user in.

Comment: you can check for password in the first block and sign in the user if the password matches. duh!